# Does ALAsset only provide thumbnail of size 150x90? Its there any way of getting larger thumbnail size, say 320x320 or 640x640?

Tags: ios, image, load, thumbnails, alasset

I tried getting a thumbnail `CGImage` from `ALAsset` class, but it only returns 120x90 pixels images on iPhone4, which look very bad. Is there a way of getting larger thumbnails (say 320x320 or 640x640)?

I want to load thumbnails quickly because full size images are taking anywhere between 0.5 to 0.9 seconds to load on my iPhone4.

Is there a solution and sample code?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `fullScreenImage` option from the `ALAssetRepresentation`.